# upload_max_filesize doesn't show in phpinfo

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

I just changed my PHP configs in `php.ini` like this :

```
post_max_size = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 100M
```

but can't see changes in `phpinfo()`. This function still displays 2M as `upload_max_filesize`. I'm using Wamp server (Apache 2.2.11, PHP 5.2.9). How can I fix this ?

Comment: Did you restart apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have multiple ini files in your system. Go to your phpinfo and check for the following entry:

```
Loaded Configuration File
```

The file indicated there is the one you have to edit for your changes to take effect. Then restart Apache/Nginx.

Also, be aware that ini settings can also be changed at an .htaccess level and even at httpd.conf. So these will take precedence over settings in your php.ini.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really have many php.ini files. Thanks @Danny H.

Answer (score 0):

Use the wampmanager menus to make sure you amend the `php.ini` file that Apache uses

```
wampmanager -> PHP -> php.ini
```

Click that link and it will open the php.ini file in the default editor, it could not be easier.

Dont forget to restart Apache when you have saved the `php.ini`, again using the menus

```
wampmanager -> Apache -> Service -> Restart Service
```